# DB quant research

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, papers

I'm trying to find DB quant research papers in "Signal Processing" series - particularly interested in "Signal Processing: The options issue" (2010). Would appreciate if anyone could share it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is not publicly available...

I have the paper but I am obviously not allowed to share it publicly. Normally the best is to contact one of the authors but I checked and it seems that all f them have left Deutsche.

As an alternative you can contact Ronnie Shah, Head of US Quantitative Strategy at Deutsche. I am also not allowed to share his contact details but google is your friend...

Hope that helps and Good luck!